# Delete a document from Marklogic staging based on a condition

Tags: marklogic

Can we delete a document from markLogic staging based on a condition? Something like delete from data-hub-STAGING where name="John"

Sample documents as below:

```
{
    "source": "source1",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-23 10:23:55"
}

{
    "source": "source2",
    "name": "John",
    "DOB": "1-01-1990",
    "load_date": "2021-10-23 10:23:55"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cts.uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uris) with a [`cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery) to obtain the list of document URIs that have a JSON property named `name` with the value "John", and then iterate over the list of URIs and call [`xdmp.documentDelete()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentDelete)

```
declareUpdate();
for (const uri of cts.uris("", null, cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", "John"))) {
  xdmp.documentDelete(uri);
}
```

The equivalent in XQuery:

```
cts:uris("", (), cts:json-property-value-query("name", "John")) ! xdmp:document-delete(.)
```